# A question about the geometric realization of a simplicial complex

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-topology

I think I have been stuck on this question for too long and I really need to know how to rigorously solve this:

Let $K=(V,S)$ be a finite Simplicial complex and let $p$ be an element not included in $V$ . We define $CK=(V∪{p}), CS)$ , $ CS$ being equal to ${a∪{p},a∈S}$ .

QUESTION: Prove that the geometric realization of $CK $is homeomorphic to the cone on the geometric realization of $K$ .

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please [edit] the question to tell us what you tried and just where you are stuck. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Roughly speaking, the points in both spaces can be identified with $tv+(1-t)p$ for $v\in|K|$ and $t\in[0,1]$ subject to some relation. If you trace through this carefully you will get the homeomorphism.